# Regular expression with repetitive pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match

%foo(%bar) or %foo.

I'm using this code now:

```
String code = "%foo(%bar)";
code.matches("%+[\w&&[^_]][\w0-9]+[\w0-9&&[^_]]");
```

but it works only in the second case.

**Edit**: My regular expression must check if the variable contain numbers and letters and if it start with _ or end with _. I don't want a match with `_%foo` or `%foo_` or `_%foo_`.

Comment: `%foo` and `%bar` are literals or placeholders?

Comment: they are just literals

Comment: Does `%[\w]+(\(%[\w]+\))?` work for you?

Comment: @Tunaki Too simple, I need to check if they contain word carachters numbers and it doesn't start/end with _

Comment: Please update the question will all the conditions then, otherwise it is a guessing game

Comment: @Tunaki I wrote my current regular expression for this reason (!)

Comment: @greywolf82 Yes, but as you say, yours do not work, so we cannot trust it

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez Ok updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct Java regular expression would be

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("%\\w+(?:\\(%\\w+\\))?");
```

No underscores in first or last place:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("%[\\w&&[^_]]\\w*[\\w&&[^_]]" +
                                  "(?:\\(%[\\w&&[^_]]\\w*[\\w&&[^_]]\\))?");
```

This pattern requires at least two characters in the name. If a single non-underscore should be accepted, the second and third part can be made optional:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("%[\\w&&[^_]](?:\\w*[\\w&&[^_]])?" +
                                  "(?:\\(%[\\w&&[^_]](?:\\w*[\\w&&[^_]])?\\))?");
```

Comment: @greywolf Lost a comment due to lousy connection, now added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `%foo` and `%bar` are words that begin with a `%` sign, the regex would be:

```
%\w+(\(%\w+\))?
```

Comment: Too simple, I need to check if they contain word carachters numbers and it doesn't start/end with

Comment: \w already matches numbers and letters. I don't understand what "it doesn't start/end with" mean

Comment: I don't want a match with _%foo or %foo_ or _%foo_

Comment: are you kidding me? :D

Comment: I'm sorry I mean the character "_"